# How to set the opacity of an overlay in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, overlay

I'm trying to set the opacity of an overlay in SwiftUI.
However, I'm **only** trying to change the opacity of the overlay, and want to keep the opacity of the symbol that is being overlayed. But, when i apply the .opacity() modifier, it changes the opacity of the whole view (both the image and the overlay)

```
                Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                    .padding(10)
                    .overlay(Color.gray)
                    .opacity(0.1)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
```

this code produces [this view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut2I5.png).

as you can see, the entire view is barely visible, and I am trying to only make the gray circle around the search icon opaque, and keep the opacity of the search icon itself.

Comment: I'm not sure you are including all the code. Where does the circular background come from? Where is the `overlay` modifier?

Comment: Also, there is a system image called `magnifyingglass.circle.fill` which has a background like that by default, if that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're adding opacity to your whole view, add it to your overlay instead:

`.overlay(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you overlaying the gray circle *on top* of the symbol? Shouldn't it be the other way around? The order of view modifiers, including `.opacity()`, are very important in SwiftUI. If you want to only adjust the opacity of the gray circle, you must attach `.opacity()` *before* the overlay.

```
Color.gray
.frame(width: 40, height: 40)
.clipShape(Circle())
.opacity(0.1) /// apply to the gray circle
.overlay( /// overlay does not get affected
    Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .padding(10)
)
```

Result:

[image: Opaque symbol on top of translucent gray circle]